# Reading the sorting criteria in jQuery Tablesorter

Tags: jquery, criteria, tablesorter

I'd like to dynamically read what columns are being used to sort the table. I tried selecting the columns with headerSortUp and headerSortDown classes, but it doesn't work with multiple-column sorting criteria.

Comment: Showing us your code might help pin down the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the current sort like this:

```
var sortList;  

$(table).tablesorter({ 
        // your options
}).bind("sortEnd", function(sorter) 
{    
    sortList = sorter.target.config.sortList; 
});
```

sortList is of the form  `[[0,0],[2,1]]` where that example means sort on the first column asc and third column, order desc